# Is there a way to use android application functionality on cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have two applications one is running on android java,the other one is a cordova application. I need to use the android functionality on the cordova app. is therere a workround to this? I have been scratching my head for a week.

I have looked into Android plugins but i don't really know how to glue them together. I know Cordova can communicate back and forth with native code. But since i am an android developer and i have little idea on how cordova works with plugins Am Stuck with just my plain Android App built on java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom requirement, then your best shot is creating a plugin for Cordova which is well documented in the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/). It will guide you on how to build as well as publish a plugin for Cordova.

Once you publish a plugin, you can add it using

```
cordova plugin add <plugin_name>
```

Comment: I have been on the documentation. I need to know how do i start creating it on my existing android app. The flow is not really explained clearly.

Comment: please tell me where you are stuck at?

Comment: I have an android app which is working fine. It reads Biometric data and NFC. I need to know how i can start from there making the plugin so that the app continues working as is.

Comment: I have seen the best way to create the plugin is using plugman...I have create a plugin with the same package name as my existing android app.

Comment: did you installed the plugin with plugman or did you actually create it with plugman?